# Item not automatically selected in intellisense dropdown

Tags: ssms

I have intellisense enabled in SSMS. When i start typing, I do see the intellisense dropdown with list of options but the option that matches what i am typing is not automatically selected. I have to use down arrowkey to select the item and then hit enter to auotcomplete. Is there any setting in SSMS to make intellisense behave the way we have it in Visual Studio?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do you mean "Toggle Completion Mode", on the Edit->Intellisense menu?

[image: SSMS Screengrab]

Comment: Same for Visual Studio (option name and shortcut)